# Pyzbar does not recognize CODE-128 barcode

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, barcode, zbar

I am trying to read text encoded in barcode - I am using `pyzbar` like this:

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("example/path")
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(img, symbols=[pyzbar.ZBarSymbol.CODE128])

print(barcodes)
```

It normally works, but in the last batch of barcodes that I have received, `pyzbar` cannot read them - output of `pyzbar.decode` is `[]`. There is one example:

[image]

I have tried to put it into [online decoder](https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/) and it decodes it just fine (it also says the barcode type is CODE-128). Anybody knows, how can I read it in Python, please?

Comment: It looks like `img = cv2.imread("example.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` and `img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]` solves the issue, but is it a valid solution?

Comment: zbar and others are needed to the preprocess steps to reproduce barcodes. What I see in your image is that it is little blurry and low contrast. You may try preprocessing steps or you may switch to the zxing library which is more accurate comparing to zbar. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcHs_mj_XRc&t=60s) also may help.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk: the image is not blurry, it is in fact too sharp. And contrast is excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture shows a lot of ringing (contours reinforced in black). That could be the reason for the failure. Try blurring the image before a read. Binarization also works seamlessly.

[image]

[image]